# Assistance with building a sports game with multiple classes

Tags: java, class, inheritance

***UPDATED CODE***I have to write a class encapsulating a sports game, which inherits from Game. Where the game has the following additional attributes: whether the game is a team or individual     game, and whether the game can end in a tie.

I am not familiar with inheritance and am wondering if you guys could help get me on the right path. I have been reading about inheritance all day and just don't understand it. My question is: how to I build build this project to incorporate inheritance, what can/should be inherited and how do you do it? Thanks

I think I may have figured a bit out, but can some one help with the toString method and how to code the canTie?

```
public class Game 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Question39 gm1 = new Question39();
    System.out.println("Game type: "+ gm1.getGameType() + "\n"
                       + "Can it tie: " + gm1.getCanTie());
}

public Game()
{

}  
}
```

Second Class

```
public class SportsGame extends Game 
{
public SportsGame()
{
    super();
}

public String toString()
{
    String output ="hey"; 
    return output;
}

 //Accessors (Getters)
public String getGameType() 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of players");
    int players = scan.nextInt();

    if (players > 2)
    {
        return "Team";
    }    
    else 
    {
        if (players ==2)
        {
            return "Individual";
        }

        else
        {
            return "N/A";
        }
    }

}

public String getCanTie()
{
    String canTie = "yes";
    String cantTie = "no";

    if (1==1) 
            {
                return canTie;
            }
    else 
            {
                return cantTie;
            }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `SportsGame` "is-a" `Game`, it should, as you say, inherit from `Game`.

The syntax for that is:

```
public class SportsGame extends Game {
    // ....
}
```

Your classes should probably be like this:

```
// In Game.java:
public abstract class Game {
    public abstract boolean isTeamGame();
    public abstract boolean canEndInTie();
}
```

```
// In SportsGame.java:
public class SportsGame extends Game {
    // You'll need to implement the methods from Game here.
    // For example:

    @Override
    public boolean isTeamGame() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canEndInTie() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could initialize those values to a variable in a constructor, and then return them from those methods.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with the "being able to tie" part of this code. this is what I have...                      public String getCanTie()
    {
        String canTie = "Yes";
        String cantTie = "No";
        
        if (players==0) 
                {
                    return cantTie;
                }
        else 
                {
                    return canTie;
                }
    }

Comment: Instead of returning `"Yes"` and `"No"`, you'll want to return `true` or `false` (no quotes) because the method returns a `boolean` not a `String`.